# How do I implement my own token type for httr authentication?

Tags: r, access-token, bearer-token, httr

I am using a web API that uses an authentication that is similar to, *but not quite*, OAuth 2.0. As a consequence, I would like to implement my own [`Token` class](https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/Token-class.html) for use by ‘httr’.

Unfortunate there are several issues:

- The `Token` base class seems to be specific to OAuth and [contains members/logic that don’t apply to me](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/blob/22e8249096d04e1b4703fae709b02cd7fdadf732/R/oauth-token.r#L48-L52).
- The [documentation](https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/Token-class.html) is incomplete and incorrect: at the very least it is missing the method for restoring a token from the cache, and it is also missing the specification for the other methods. It also specifies an incorrect return type for `sign()` (the calling code inside ‘httr’ expects a `request` S3 object).
- To implement `sign()` correctly, I need to use an unexported function, `httr:::request()`.

The expected usage for me would be as follows, given a valid `token` from a previous authorisation request:

```
httr::GET(endpoint_url, bearer_auth(token))
```

Where:

```
bearer_auth = function (token) {
    httr::config(token = BearerToken$new(token))
}
```

This “works” when creating a minimal `BearerToken` R6 class that doesn’t inherit from `httr::Token`, implements only the `sign()` method, and cheats by accessing `httr:::request()`:

```
BearerToken = R6::R6Class("BearerToken", list(
  token = NULL,

  initialize = function (token) {
    self$token = token
  },

  sign = function (method, url) {
    httr:::request(
      method = method,
      url = url,
      headers = c(Authorization = paste("Bearer", self$token))
    )
  }
))
```

But that’s obviously insufficient for real usage.

Comment: Not able to help with your problem, but flagging that [httr2](https://httr2.r-lib.org/index.html) may handle authentication differently. Not sure if it will be helpful / if it does handle things differently, but I did want to raise it in-case you were not aware.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, I hadn't realised that version 2 of the package would obviously be a different package. R package "versioning" is driving me insane.

Comment: Ha, yeah, I was surprised to find httr2 as well. I suppose the vision for version 2 had too many breaking changes for even a major version increase. I have been transitioning my work from httr to httr2 as-needed (aware that things may change before httr2 increments to v1.0).

Comment: If httr2 does not help you in the short-term, it may be worth submitting an issue so the package can include functionality before v1.